# unknown bytes is returned by method getBytes()

Tags: java, string, unicode

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  try 
  {
   String s = "s";
   System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getBytes("utf8") ) );
   System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getBytes("utf16") ) );
   System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getBytes("utf32") ) );
  }  
  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Console:

```
[115]
[-2, -1, 0, 115]
[0, 0, 0, 115]
```

What is it?

[-2, -1] - ???

Also, i noted, that if i do that:

```
String s = new String(new char[]{'\u1251'});
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getBytes("utf8") ) );
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getBytes("utf16") ) );
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getBytes("utf32") ) );
```

Console:

```
[-31, -119, -111]
[-2, -1, 18, 81]
[0, 0, 18, 81]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -2, -1 is a Byte Order Mark (BOM - U+FEFF) that indcates that the following text is encoded in UTF-16 format.

You are probably getting this because, while there is only one UTF8 and UTF32 encoding, there are two UTF16 encodings UTF16LE and UTF16BE, where the 2 bytes in the 16-bit value are stored in Big-Endian or Little Endian format.

As the values that come back are 0xFE xFF, this suggests that the encoding is UTF16BE

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget that bytes are unsigned in Java. So -2, -1 really means 0xfe 0xff... and U+FEFF is the Unicode [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM)... that's what you're seeing here in the UTF-16 version.

To avoid getting the BOM when encoding, use UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE explicitly. (I would also suggest using the [names which are guaranteed by the platform](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) rather than just "utf8" etc. Admittedly the name is guaranteed to be found case-insensitively, but the lack of a hyphen makes it less reliable, and there are no downsides to using the canonical name.)

Comment: +1 for having 238k rep.  You must know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The mysterious `-2, -1` is a UTF-16 [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  The other negative values are simply bytes.  In Java, the `byte` type is signed, and ranges from `-128` to `+127`.

Answer (score 2):

A byte in java is a signed type, so it is entirely normal for it to have negative values.